# Filter mysql database with flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have an issue trying to get 'usernames' column from a database filtering on the logged-in user. Filtering on the logged-in user works, but not the "please don't get me anything else than what is in the column username where the userID is x"

The flask code that runs:

```py
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
from flask import Blueprint, redirect, render_template, url_for, request, flash
from .models import Logins, Users
from .security import encrypt, decrypt
from . import db

viewlogins = Blueprint('viewlogins', __name__)

@viewlogins.route('/viewlogins')
@login_required
def viewlogin():
    username=Logins.query.filter_by(userID=current_user.id and column.username).all()
    return render_template('viewlogins.html',name=current_user.name, login=username)
```

and the model script:

```py
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from . import db

class Logins(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    location = db.Column(db.String(100))
    username = db.Column(db.String(100))
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    url = db.Column(db.String(255))
    note = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    userID = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

tldr:
please help me make this line work in flask-sqlalchemy with model script

```
SELECT username FROM Logins WHERE userID IS x
```

Comment: So you want to specify the column that you ate getting? Example only get the username column?

Answer (score 0):

To select columns to be included on the query result you could add with_entities

```py
Logins.query.with_entities(Logins.username).filter(Logins.userID == x).all()
```